# Merge/combine two React Native apps into one app

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I have a React Native app developed using Expo and I have to somehow integrate it with other React Native app that doesn't use Expo. An additional requirement is that this other app (without Expo) needs to stay somewhat independent, that is, there has to be the possibility of developing independently and using it as a standalone app. One idea that I have is to create a third app and include those two in it as some kind of dependency. But I don't really know if it's possible and how to even start doing it. Searching the internet doesn't really help. Is such a kind of merge even a thing? Can I somehow treat a whole app as a component and include two such components in a third app? Or maybe I have to extract components from these two apps and build the third with them? It is actually my first encounter with React Native, so I would be grateful for any guidance.

Comment: Could @Ryuu or RegRom choose the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

It is kind of a tricky question, but I think I understood what you want.

You want to pass a data from one app to another, just like `messenger`, `instagram`, `facebook` and `threads` does between each other, right?

If so, here's what can be done using `good app development pratics`:

1. Use an API to "connect" a user from `app A` to a user in `app B`, using their own account data, like e-mail or username. This is how the meta apps do it.
2. Using a functionality called [`Deep Linking`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) you can share data between any apps that have it set-up.
   **Example**: By using a link inside `app A`, you can call `app B` and send a parameter like a token, mail or username.
   This is how WhatsApp can send you directly to a phone number using a link like this: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=11111111111

*Note: If you choose to use Deep Linking (Which if you don't use an API on your apps already, is the best and easier outcome of the 2 options I provided you), You will need to specify which apps your app can connect to on the IOS version, on your `ios/info.plist` file, so it is something you might need to account for.*

About "Creating a third app and including `app A` and `app B` as a dependency":

*An app is an app, you can't just "merge" them. Every app has its own name, ID, version, certificate. You can't just merge 2 apps in one, neither would it be good to maintain it.*

Answer (score 0):

I guess something you could do is create a library of components out of the first 2 apps which you would like to implement in your third app. I thinks it's not possible to merge 2 apps if one of them uses expo that easy, if you try to implement features from the expo app into the react native one you're gonna have to do some changes and implement other dependencies different than what expo provides, if it's the other way around that that might be easier but I think there's gonna be some dependency compatibility as well.

What I would do is export the necessary components of one app as a library or even just copy paste them, insert them into the other app and adjusting it's dependencies for it to work correctly. I don't think there's any other way around

Answer (score 0):

Well, that sounds tricky, but that's what I would try to do:

1. Make a third project, not expo but native.
2. Add expo as a native module to support expo modules.
3. Add two projects as git submodules.
4. Add dependencies from both projects. Also, try to keep them as similar as possible in each sub project. You may also need to use "resolutions" section of `package.json` to fix some dependencies conflicts.
5. Import components, for example root ones, of both apps to your new project from project folders.
6. Resolve found issues.

Another way, without git submodules, is to put all reusable js/ts code to private npm packages and use them in all three projects. But that will require additional configuration of npm registry and CI/CD, without much benefit.